# Get the predicted value for the next day in time series linear regression

Tags: python-3.x, machine-learning, time-series, linear-regression

I have two dataframes, say features and target as below

features.head()

```
    exp_1   exp_2   exp_3
Date            
2019-01-02  0.354617    1.000000    0.246518
2019-01-03  0.240598    0.805193    0.792160
2019-01-04  0.263682    1.000000    0.463351
2019-01-07  0.266451    0.616858    0.424852
2019-01-08  0.282567    0.694753    0.286588
```

and target.head()

```
Date
2019-01-02    0.354617
2019-01-03    0.240598
2019-01-04    0.263682
2019-01-07    0.266451
2019-01-08    0.282567
```

can i predict the value of 2019-01-09? i tried below code

```
model = linear_model.LinearRegression()
model.fit(features, target)
model.predict(features)
```

It's giving me like a list, so how to identify the data for next dates?

PS: i'm new to machine learning, so forgive me in case of any mistake.

Comment: can you post the full code on what you have tried.. besides this, the approach your following is incorrect. You need to identify the feature that contributes maximum to a model. For instance, looking at the featureset, split the date into year, month and day format. Then remove the feature with constant variance like year in this case. Create model on day and month features.

Comment: @mnm, for beginign let's just assume all features are equilly contributing,

Comment: i reiterate, show the full code and revise the Q. Absence of which will invite downvotes.